# HTTPS to HTTPS header showing no-referrer-when-downgrade

Tags: javascript, ssl, web, https

I am trying to use document.referrer to customize the user experience if they are coming from sites like Glassdoor or Linkedin. My site has an SSL certificate (through GoDaddy) and is using HTTPS (like Glassdoor and Linkedin), but when I run document.referrer I get "".

- [Calling document.referrer in Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymC2z.png)
- [Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xkGc.png)

Has anyone experienced this before? Any tips?

Comment: Please don't include textual information as images but include these as text. Apart from that, check [referrer policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) of the origin site and any `referrerpolicy` or `rel` attributes on the links which point to your site.